# Redmine Rails server stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, redmine

Just cloned a Redmine source code from github using `git clone git://github.com/redmine/redmine.git`, then run `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`. After that, the following error occurs when I run the `rails server`.

I am running `MacOS Sierra` with `ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]` and `Rails 4.2.3`.

Anyone has the solution for this issue? How can I solve it?

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb1Bz.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in older versions of rails, caused by the unification of FixNum and Integer in ruby 2.4. For more information, check out the [bug report discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25125).

I'm looking at the repository now, and it sure looks like redmine has since fixed the issue and is now using rails 4.2.8; however your error suggests you're on rails 4.2.3.

You should run `git pull` to update your clone. If for some reason you want to use the old version of redmine, you'll have to downgrade to ruby 2.3.